# How can I find my mistake in the create route?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, typescript

The task is to write a create route for a user registration, starting with the html, over the client typescript and server typescript to my sql database. I don't even know if the mistake is in my client or server.

I have already tried debugging it with the console and debugger. Running the server works and loading the .js works as well. So I think the mistake must be either in the function on the client.ts oder the function / routing on the server.ts (or maybe both).

client.ts

```
    function registrierung(event: Event): void {
        event.preventDefault();

        const vnamex: string = vname.val().toString();
        const nnamex: string = nname.val().toString();
        const strassex: string = strasse.val().toString();
        const hnrx: string = hnr.val().toString();
        const plzx: string = plz.val().toString();
        const ortx: string = ort.val().toString();
        const emailx: string = email.val().toString();
        const passwortx: string = passwort.val().toString();

     $.ajax({
                   contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                   data: "vname=" + vnamex + "&nname=" + nnamex +
        "&strasse=" + strassex + "&hnr=" + hnrx + "&plz=" + plzx + "&ort=" + ortx +
        "&email=" + emailx + "&passwort=" + passwortx,

        type: "POST",
        url: "/register",
    });
    }
```

server.ts

```
    const createQuery: string = "INSERT INTO person" + "(vname, nname, strasse, hnr, plz, ort, email, passwort) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

    router.post("/register", regserver);

    function regserver(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {

        const vname: string = req.body.vname;
        const nname: string = req.body.nname;
        const strasse: string = req.body.strasse;
        const hnr: string = req.body.hnr;
        const plz: string = req.body.plz;
        const ort: string = req.body.ort;
        const email: string = req.body.email;
        const passwort: string = req.body.passwort;

       connection.query(createQuery, [vname, nname, strasse, hnr, plz, ort, email, passwort],
            (err: mysql.MysqlError | null) => {
                if (err === null) {
                    res.sendStatus(201);
                } else {
                    res.sendStatus(500);
                }
            });
    }
```

So the data from the input fields in my html should create a new line in my sql table "person".